# Haystack + Django CMS search error "reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value"

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, django-cms

I'm relatively new to the Django world. Our client wants to add a search feature to their site so I'm integrating Haystack and Aldryn Search as described here:

https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-search

I've also gone through here: https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.0/tutorial.html

> Exception Location: env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/backends/simple_backend.py in search, line 79

Here are some helpful information snippets:

urls.py -

```
(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
```

templates/search/search.html -

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="primary-content">
<div class="container constrained">
    <form method="get" class="paragraph" action=".">
        {{ form.as_table }}
        <div class="text-right">
            <button type="submit" class="button">
                Search
            </button>
        </div>

        {% if query %}
            <h3>Results</h3>

            {% for result in page.object_list %}
                <div class="post-preview paragraph">
                    <h3>
                        <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.object.title }}</a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
            {% empty %}
                <p>No results found.</p>
            {% endfor %}

            {% if page.has_previous or page.has_next %}
                <div>
                    {% if page.has_previous %}<a href="?q={{ query }}&amp;page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">{% endif %}&laquo; Previous{% if page.has_previous %}</a>{% endif %}
                    |
                    {% if page.has_next %}<a href="?q={{ query }}&amp;page={{ page.next_page_number }}">{% endif %}Next &raquo;{% if page.has_next %}</a>{% endif %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
            {# Show some example queries to run, maybe query syntax, something else? #}
        {% endif %}
    </form>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

settings.py -

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.simple_backend.SimpleEngine',
},
}
HAYSTACK_ROUTERS = ['aldryn_search.router.LanguageRouter', ]
ALDRYN_SEARCH_REGISTER_APPHOOK = True
ALDRYN_SEARCH_PAGINATION = 20
ALDRYN_SEARCH_CMS_PAGE = True
```

Additionally, both 'haystack' and 'aldryn_search' are in INSTALLED_APPS.

When I run update_index --remove it does seem to work for the most part:

```
Indexing 5 locations
Indexing 2 People
Indexing 16 articles
```

It looks like I've done everything right according to the documentation. But I must not be. We only have one language on the site so that does make the documentation a little hard to comprehend for me because I'm not sure if I have extra things that are only needed for multi lingual.

Stack trace:

```
['/build/healthdirect',
 '/build/env/lib/python27.zip',
 '/build/env/lib/python2.7',
 '/build/env/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/build/env/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/build/env/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/build/env/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/build/env/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/build/env/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
```

'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
         '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
     '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
     '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
     '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
     '/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Comment: Please include the full traceback for the error in the question text.

Comment: @HåkenLid added

Comment: That's not a traceback.